# ASP.NET - C# - Retrieve username and compare to SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I have a `SQL` database named "administration" with usernames and roles.

What I would like to do with my ASP.NET application is:

once someone accesses my intranet site, I get their username using

`string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`

Then I check if that username is in my database. I assume I can do this with an `IF EXISTS` statement.

However I'm not sure how I would do the following: **IF** the user is in the database I want to display the Web Page as per their role (i.e. all pages are different Admin = see all content and buttons, User = all content no buttons).

However if their username is not in my database I will display a blank page or something along the lines of "Access Denied".

This is the way I have been asked to do it but I cant seem to work it out.

Is it possible?

Comment: of course it's possible. We're programmers. If-Then conditions will be needed to decide what to display. But even more logic can be replaced with lookup variables like `name`, `role`, etc. any data stored in your user db can become display variables.

Comment: What you are talking about is roles-based security - people can only see what their assigned roles allow them to see.  Take a look at [Role-Based Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shz8h065.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

after getting userName.

```
sqlconnection cn = new sqlconnection("give connectionstring");
cn.open();
   sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand();
   cmd.commandtext = "select * from "table"; // table name give.
   cmd.connection = cn;
   sqldatareader rdr = cmd.executereader();
   while(rdr.read()){
        if(stringName = rdr[columnnumber].toString());
             flag = true;
   }
   if(flag)
    //take decesion
   else
   // take decesion.
cn.close();
```

you can achieve it like this. u can use. it. bt there are some mistake in syntax i roughly write for u.